# How to 'mutate' mixed data (i.e., numeric and range values) within single column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, mutate

I "grew up" on old-school `R` slicing, etc. and am trying to learn the `tidyr` ways.

I'm currently working with messy electronic health record data where entries for some patients are specific numeric values (e.g., "16"), while others would be a range (e.g., "25-30".

I want to convert all entries into ordered ranges (e.g., "<20", "20-29", etc.) using `mutate` (unless that's not the best way to do this).

**Ultimate question**: Is there an elegant way to `mutate` all "numeric" values into their respective range? I assume I'll need individual `mutate` statements for the ranges that don't match how I want them grouped, but it would be nice to not need a `mutate` statement for every numeric value I encounter.

**Current approach**

To clarify, here's how I'm curring using `mutate` for every individual value I see in the column:

```
...
mutate(<some_column> = str_replace(<some_column>, "^16$", "<20")) %>%
mutate(<some_column> = str_replace(<some_column>, "^17$", "<20")) %>%
...
```

**Ideal approach**

I'd like to be able to do something more elegant/intelligent like the following pseudocode, but in a `tidyr` way:

```
if(is.numeric(as.numeric(<value>))){
    if(as.numeric(<value>) < 20){
        #set value to "<20" to create ordered groups.
        <value> <- "<20"
    }
}
```

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: This seems easiest/best done with `base::cut`. If the ranges are identical for all columns, then something like `dat %>% mutate(across(c(col1, col2, col3), ~ cut(., breaks=c(0, 20, 99), labels=c("<20", "20-98", ">=99"))))` might work. It'd be easier to inform with sample data and expected output.

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably first convert the character column you're dealing with into two numeric columns representing a min & max. So "<20" would be (0,20) or (-Inf,20), and "17" would just be (17,17). That way you'd have a consistent format across all records.